# Does one congruence imply the other?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

If $a \equiv b \pmod n \: \:$ and $\: \: a \equiv 0 \pmod n \: \:, \: b \equiv 0 \pmod n$

Is it implied that $a \equiv 0 \pmod b$ ? i.e if $b \leq a$

The specific context of this question is that of the multiples of 9. That is we know that for any multiple of 9, not only is the number divisible by 9, but also the sum of its digits. So is it true that the number is divisible by the sum of the digits?

**Update** Ok so I found a counterexample for the generalization of my question, but is the part about multiples of 9 true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true that
$$a\equiv b\equiv 0\bmod n\implies a\equiv 0\bmod b$$
For example, we can look at $n=2$, $a=6$, and $b=4$.

---

For your other question: no, just because
$$n\equiv 0\bmod 9\implies \operatorname{digit\_sum}(n)\equiv 0\bmod 9$$
does not mean that
$$n\equiv 0\bmod 9\implies n\equiv 0\bmod \operatorname{digit\_sum}(n)$$
For example, consider $n=99$. Then $\operatorname{digit\_sum}(99)=18$ but
$99\not\equiv 0\bmod 18$.

Comment: Yeah I figured, but is it true for the multiples of 9?

Comment: Just as an aside, is this property true for 3 digit multiples of 9? The reason I'm asking is because I'm reading Tao's "Solving Mathematical Problems" and in the proof of one question, he seems to use this property.

Comment: For $n=189$, we have $n\equiv 0\bmod 9$ but $\operatorname{digit\_sum}(189)=18$ and $189\not\equiv0\bmod 18$.

Comment: Yeah I read more about it, the property holds for multiples of 18.

Comment: @Airdish: That's still not true; for example, $18181818\equiv 0\bmod 9$ and $18181818$ is a multiple of $18$, but $\operatorname{digit\_sum}(18181818)=36$ and $18181818\not\equiv 0\bmod 36$.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific: 3 digit multiples of 18